# Basic GET request failed Angular and Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors, angular9

I am trying to make a simple request from angular to spring. I used bare bone spring web and spring security and simple angular(9) request.

Let me share my Java and Angular code.

Java Code

```
@RestController @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class Main {

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public Map<String,Object> home(){
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    model.put("content", "Hello from Backend");
    return model;
    }
}
```

Angular side auth.componen.ts file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-auth',
    templateUrl: './auth.component.html'
})
export class AuthComponent{
    isLoginMode = true;
    title = 'Demo';
    greeting = {};

    onSwitchMode(){
        this.isLoginMode = !this.isLoginMode;
    }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm){
        console.log(form.value);
        form.reset(); 
    }

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){
        http.get('http://localhost:8080/hello').subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
    }
}
```

HTML side

```
<div style="text-align:center"class="container">
  <h1>
    Welcome {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Id: <span>{{greeting.id}}</span></p>
    <p>Message: <span>{{greeting.content}}!</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am following the [this link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) but every time I get this error:
[image: Error message I get]

Edit 1:
Chrome developer tools Network tab result:
[image: Network Tab on Chrome]

I tried to search online but can't find the answer. Can you help me to continue?

Comment: I see you have cors enabled with an annotation. Just to make sure, your angular app is running on http://localhost:4200 ?

Comment: Hello @CezaryButler yes my angular app runs on http://localhost:4200 and my request page is http://localhost:4200/auth

Comment: Could you post also part of the Chrome network tab with the preflight request? It seems like despite annotation present the spring did not add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: I edited the my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Security, Cors filter is to be additionally configured.

Here is the reference from Spring Documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cors.html

> Spring Framework provides first class support for CORS. CORS must be processed before Spring Security because the pre-flight request will not contain any cookies (i.e. the JSESSIONID). If the request does not contain any cookies and Spring Security is first, the request will determine the user is not authenticated (since there are no cookies in the request) and reject it.
>
> The easiest way to ensure that CORS is handled first is to use the
> CorsFilter

Cors filter can simply be configured through WebSecurityConfigurerAdapeter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // if Spring MVC is on classpath and no CorsConfigurationSource is provided,
        // Spring Security will use CORS configuration provided to Spring MVC
        .cors().and()
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for late.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot from the console explains quite well why it failed. For sure you're running angular application on different URL than the spring one.

In order to allow the angular application to communicate with the spring backend, you need to configure CORS policy on the backend which is covered [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#controller-method-cors-configuration)

Looks like your browser for some reason didn't send a preflight request.
Maybe you'll find explanation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests)

Comment: Hello you can see my Java code there is an annotation as @CrossOrigin.

Comment: @MertalpTasdelen I've verified and indeed with spring-security additional cors filter configuration is needed as in user11244881 answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the timing.